# Can't uninstall a program

Tags: facebook

After installing Ubuntu for the first time on an old laptop, I navigated to firefox and went to facebook. Upon entering the website, I was prompted to install a piece of software called 'FacebookMessenger', which I now cannot remove. There is no uninstall button present.

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain your installed or install packages using Synaptic Package Manager:

Open a Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

go to **Dash** and type `Synaptic` click on it you'll get a window like this:

[image]

type `facebook` for example in quick filter and see what packages you have installed click on `green marked or ticked` space next to the package that you wish to remove and choose complete removal.

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed it? From Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic, or command line?
If you don't remember any, probably you didn't install it, you just download it. If you can remember,  just go back to where you installed it: Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic have "remove" button once you locate the item, or from command line, you type:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge PACKAGENAME
```

replace PACKAGENAME with FacebookMassenger or something your item named.